# How to upload the files using HTTP and and command line tools?

Tags: php, command-line, file-upload, lamp

I have a LAMP server. I have only Http(80) and HTTPS(443) ports are open. 
The users can upload files using **PHP** form. 
Some users are downloading files using `wget`. 
Are there way to upload files using command line tools?

thank you beforehand.
Arman

**SOLUTION**(thanks to R. Bemrose)
using the libcurl One can upload files from command line:
nice tutorial: http://www.maheshchari.com/upload-image-file-to-remote-server-with-php-curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curl` library has a [command line tool](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).  I forget the exact options to do it, but `curl` can be used to post files as if it were from a form.

Edit:
The appropriate option seems to be `-F "fileFieldName=@/path/to/file;otherField=otherValue;moreFields=moreValues"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload a file directly on a server without any kind of protocol and if you can, this will be a huge security issue.

Try looking at the ftp shell commands in Linux

Comment: He explicitly mentions two protocols: HTTP and HTTPS.