# Windows interface to a web application

Tags: php, windows, webserver

I have a simple web application written in PHP. You can log in and upload/download some files. Now I want to integrate those functions into windows. Imagine a user right clicks a file and can click to `Upload to my application`. The system automatically sends those file to the webserver via `POST` and maybe get even a reply back from the webserver. Is there a good solution for something like that?

Comment: [irony]Yes, writing a Windows application for this purpose[/irony]. Ok to be serious, you may write your own application or check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4268959/1207195) for uploading and [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/) (to add an item to context menu).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thank you! I will take a look at it, but it looks very promising.